# Calling polars apply results in an error message

Tags: python, python-polars

This:

```
df = polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=numpy.random.randint(10, 99, 10),
  k=numpy.random.randint(10, 99, 10),
  ))

def f(cell):
  # Simulate logic that cannot be done in polars alone
  # E.g. call external REST service that returns "success" => True
  return cell > 50

print(df.select(polars.all().apply(f)))
```

Causes this:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ComputeError(ErrString("wildcard has no root column name"))', /home/runner/work/polars/polars/crates/polars-plan/src/utils.rs:207:47
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

with polars 0.18.11, though it does finish and produces the expected result. What's the above about and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is a bug in Polars. What triggers the error message is the use of the wildcard `pl.all()`. A more minimalistic example:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})

result = df.select(pl.all().apply(lambda x: x > 50))
# thread '<unnamed>' panicked ...
```

Replacing `pl.all()` with `pl.col("a")` will not result in the error message.

I have opened a bug report in the Polars repo to solve this issue. You can track it [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10237).

UPDATE: The issue has been resolved. Once a new Python release is issued (`0.18.12`), you can upgrade to the new version and the error message should no longer show.

Comment: FWIW, my python 3.11.4 / polars 0.18.7 computes this and the OP expression just fine, without panic or warnings. So it's a recent regression.

Comment: Well that was lightning fast, thanks!